# How to connect to DB and retrieve data from DB?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Im using XAMPP. and im trying to dump my db_data on the webpage. the error message is **"call to undefined function mysql_connect"**. should i import some file?

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT *
  FROM uam';

mysql_select_db('demo');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  echo "Tutorial ID :{$row['id']}  <br> ".
     "username: {$row['username']} <br> ".
     "email: {$row['email']} <br> ".
     "password : {$row['password']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Or should i make changes in my code??

Comment: Don't use the mysql functions. It's undefined because it's been removed from PHP 7. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @Don'tPanic This should be an answer.

Comment: There's also 0 need for you to ever output a password, encrypted or not.

Comment: @Mark The comment was just a placeholder while I found the duplicate to CV.

Comment: @Don'tPanic My only concern about linking to that duplicate is that we don't know if he's really using PHP7.

Comment: @Mark I think it's a safe assumption. With XAMPP, the appropriate MySQL functions should be included. If it was an old version of XAMPP, the mysql extension would be available.

Comment: @Mark@Don'tPanic it is 7.1.8

Answer (score 1):

avoid using MySQL functions, they are now depreciated that is why you get
the undefined error, and its also not more supported in PHP 7.

use MySQLI function by changing your config to the code below

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost , $dbuser, $dbpass,  $dbname);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That happened because the new versions of PHP no support mysql_connect
try using mysqli_connect

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'demo';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

Comment: OR you could/should use PDO.

Comment: Yes I use PDO because it is more protect bu he wanted to work with mysqli_connect so I answered by this

Comment: No, he was working with an outdated API. You're making an assumption.

Answer (score -1):

```
     <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = '';
     $dbname = 'TUTORIALS';
     $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

     if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
     }
     echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
     $sql = 'SELECT name FROM tutorials_inf';
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
        }
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```